# How to access json object am keep getting undefined error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have tried to parse json and iterates it. After some nesting i was not able to get the object. it keeps saying undefined. Can anybody tell me how to access this.

```
 $.each( data[widget_val[0]][j],function(key,value){
            alert(data[widget_val[0]][j][key]); //getting output
        alert(data[widget_val[0]][j]['Type']);  //getting undefined
       });
```

my json

```
({'Encounter Date  ':"06/09/2008 ", 'Description  ':"new patient ", 'Type  ':"Note ", 'Status  ':"ARC ", 'Provider  ':"Brady, Roseann "})
```

so i am getting alert for each key even for 'Type'.But when i gave it as seprately as string i am getting undefined error. can any body tell why. What is the way to access it?

Comment: It looks like your receiving JSONP, instead of JSON. In you're request, can you request dataType: JSON?

Comment: That's not valid JSON as you can check at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Beware of spaces. Your Type attribute name is `Type  `

Comment: looks like you need remove brackets ()

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
alert(data[widget_val[0]][j]['Type  '])
```

with spaces instead of

```
alert(data[widget_val[0]][j]['Type'])
```

because you are trying access undefined variable 'Type'